# javascript - how to format the phone number with dial code with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to make `(886) 7199 2483` to `+886 7199 2483` using regex?

I can only extract the dial code by

```
const dialCode = '(886) 7199 2483'.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]; // 886
```

but don't know how to do the next step

Comment: Just use replace instead of match: `'(886) 7199 2483'.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, "+$1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use group match to do it,[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/h1t7i7/1)

```js
let str = `(886) 7199 2483`
str = str.replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "+$1")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: I don't want the `()`

Comment: @CCCC just follow adiga's comment,you will get it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general `match()` approach:

```js
var input = "(886) 7199 2483";
var output = "+" + input.match(/\d+/g).join(" ");
console.log(output);
```